# Removing elements leaves behind ng-repeat comments

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made an inventory that lists items and some items allow you to click them to see similar items. When i remove the similar item elements after the user closes the list of them, it leaves behind...

```
<!-- ngRepeat: item in category.items(3606) | orderBy:'sort_order' -->
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in category.items(3606) | orderBy:'sort_order' -->
```

which causes problems because whenever those items are updated else where in the scope, angular recreates the ng-repeat and displays it. Am i destroying the element wrong?

```
app.directive('similar', function($rootScope, $compile, $templateCache, Item, Allo){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            var unqId = _.uniqueId('similar');

            elem.on('click', function(){

                // if user closes the list of similar items, destroy the contents
                if (elem.hasClass('glyphicon-upload')) {
                    elem.removeClass('glyphicon-upload');
                    angular.element('.'+ unqId).remove();
                    return;
                }

                elem.addClass('glyphicon-upload');

                var itemId = scope.$parent.item.id;
                var similars = scope.similars[itemId];

                if (similars) {

                    var row = $templateCache.get('inventory/views/_row.htm');

                    var html = $compile('<tr class="'+ unqId +'" ng-repeat="item in category.items('+ similars +') | orderBy:\'sort_order\'">'+ row +'</tr>')(scope);

                    elem.parents('tr').after(html);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, DOM manipulation of this sort is typically unnecessary in a directive. You can most likely achieve what you want with something like:

```
<table similar ng-hide="similar_items.length == 0">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in similar_items" ...>
   <!-- contents of inventory/views/_row.htm here -->      
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `table` will be hidden, and the set of `<tr>`s empty when `similar_items` is likewise empty, so then you'll need to set that in your scope:

```
elem.on('click', function() {
   ...
   var itemId = scope.$parent.item.id;
   var similars = scope.similars[itemId];   
   scope.similar_items = category.items(similars);
});
```

You won't need to manipulate the DOM manually at all - angular will bind to the `similar_items` attribute in the scope, and do the right thing w.r.t your `<tr>`. You can add/ remove the `glyphicon-upload` class via similar mechanisms, although what purpose a class on a hidden element would serve is left as an exercise :)

That *may* fix your left-behind comments issue; I've experienced the same issue under different circumstances (modifying the scope's model after an animation completes), but have yet to resolve it.